# Какая разница между 'OR' і '||' в postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Какая разница между '`OR`' і '`||`' в postgreSQL?

SQL:

```
select distinct(us.email), us.id 
from users us 
left join aliases al on al.user_name like us.email `||` '_%' 
where us.email;
```

Sql тянет разные данные в зависимости от то стоит `OR` или `||`. Почему?

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример с OR. потому как OR это логический оператор. А `||` - это объединение строк. Если в вашем примере поставить OR то будет ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: А в MySQL `OR` это тоже логический оператор, а `||` тоже конкатенация?

Comment: @Mike, по-моему Giovanni прав http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or в MySQL поразрядное ИЛИ это |, а OR и || - синонимы.